# Can stored procedure use created Index over a table in oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, indexing

i have stored procedure that takes 3.5 second to execute.
my sp is in below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ProcTest (columnNumber   IN     VARCHAR2,
                                      TG                OUT VARCHAR2)
IS
   stmt   VARCHAR2 (1000);
BEGIN
   TG := 't' || TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') || columnNumber;
   stmt :=
      'CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE ' || TG
      || ' ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS AS (SELECT * FROM USER1.Tbl WHERE CHARGINGPARTY='
      || columnNumber
      || ')';

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stmt;
END;
```

i execute this part (CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE ' || TG 
  || ' ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS AS (SELECT * FROM USER1.Tbl WHERE CHARGINGPARTY=' || columnNumber  || ')'  ) in sql developer, and it takes 0.2s, but when i execute the sp, it takes 3.2.

i created an index on my table(USER1.Tbl),
when i run the create table query in sql developer before creating that index, it took 3.2s.

My question is:
Does sp uses indexes? or how can i force the sp to use an index???

Answer (score 3):

In general indexes are used by Oracle optimizer regardless from where the query is executed (Stored Procedure Vs Query from SQL Developer).

Based on whether you have enabled statistics gathering (by default it is enabled I believe), the optimizer decides to use the index or not depending on the statistics metrics for the table in the query (There are cases were querying directly the table would be faster rather than using the index. Usually this is when number of records is low).

Without being sure which query was executed first, there is also a possibility that you have faced the case where query result was stored in the buffer cache (from the first execution using the Stored Procedure) and when re-executing the query from SQL Developer, performance was much better because of this as there was no need to access the disk.

In the case where you want to direct the query to use your index you could use a [hint](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGSQL/tgsql_influence.htm#TGSQL260)